# Strange behaviour with right bit shift

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

Could someone explain me why the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
    unsigned char i = 2;
    std::cout<<std::bitset<8>((~static_cast<unsigned char>(0)) << i)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<std::bitset<8>((~static_cast<unsigned char>(0)) >> i)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Produces:

```
11111100
11111111
```

and not:

```
11111100
00111111
```

Comment: Don't use bitwise complement to set all bits, use `static_cast<unsigned char>(-1)` instead, and you'll get the expected result

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Before `~` is done `static_cast<unsigned char>(0)` is converted to `int` (integer promotion happens), so after `~` it becomes all-one bits `int`. This then is shifted and truncated to 8 bits in bitset.

Comment: Which is quite baffling, since you explicitly asked for an `unsigned char`; but that's what the standard says.

Comment: If you cast to `unsigned int` instead of `unsigned char` then the promotion wouldn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

On right-shifts, signed values are zero-filled on if the most significant bit is 0, and one-filled if the most significant bit is 1.

Using unsigned values forces zero-filling on right shifts.

Comment: Look at the question carefully, they attempted to use an unsigned value.